# Chat-messengers for Android and Windows devices, but not American or Russian

Tags: windows, gratis, android, chat

As it's been a bit noisy these days, I've thought that it may be a good time to migrate to a new chat-messenger.
Yes, I've decided to quit WhatsApp, Signal, Telegram. No need to worry about my mates, I am sure they will follow my recommendation if the substitute turns out to be as good. Preference will be given to Chinese or Indian messengers, but I am ready to consider other as well.

Is the below list complete?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cross-platform_instant_messaging_clients

The criteria are as follows

1. The origination of the messenger must be neither USA, nor Russia
2. High number of users
3. Both Android and Windows devices must be supported
4. Support of 2FA
5. Support of client-client encryption as both Telegram and Signal have
6. Support of voice-messages
7. Support of other "standard" functions that WhatsApp or Telegram would have (like video-calls)
8. Must be free

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't really get the rationale behind the "no united states or russia programs". Look after the developer, not the country. There are both trustworthy and malicious people in both sides, like in the whole world.

Comment: There is no need to question my inquiry. If you can't propose anything besides Chinese WeChat, then someone else may pop in to share some more insight.

Answer (score 1):

The one and (as far as I know) only option that fits those many fine requirements is [Matrix](https://matrix.org/).